# How to align words to the right using java script

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, split, alignment

I have a function with couple of words. I need to print them in one column, aligning to the right. Each word should be printed on a new line.
For example 'I will get everything I want" =>
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8MNi.png)
"         I
will
get
everything
I
want"

Comment: Where are you printing? To the console?

Comment: How do you know how wide the output should be?

Comment: @Ruan yes. in the console. With just java script,

Comment: @evelutionxbox It should align with the longest word's length

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with the pure javascript by using [String.prototype.padStart()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart)

```js
const alignWordsToTheRight = (text) => {
  const words = text.split(' ');
  const longestWord = words.reduce((a, b) => (a.length > b.length ? a : b));
  const padGivenWords = words.map(word => word.padStart(longestWord.length + 15));
  return padGivenWords.join('\n');
}

const alignedWords = alignWordsToTheRight("I will get everything I want");

console.log(alignedWords);
```

Comment: @getir Teşekkür ederim! Thank you, really appreciate it!